# Playing sound from a website in a webview?

Tags: java, android, webview, text-to-speech

**Hello scripterfriends,** I'm working on an application that reads text from a website. We have made the site already ([medispeak.eu](http://medispeak.eu/%22Medispeak%22)) and 'opened'it in a webview. But the problem is, the text to speech function doesn't work inside the app, but it does in a regular browser.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

This is the errorlog:

> 6-23 09:53:51.889 17188-17188/hobby_pc.medispeak I/chromium:
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(8)] "ResponsiveVoice r1.4.7", source:
>   https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js (8) 06-23
>   09:53:51.999 17188-17188/hobby_pc.medispeak V/ActivityThread:
>   updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{369df6d0
>   token=android.os.BinderProxy@38d5c740
>   {hobby_pc.medispeak/hobby_pc.medispeak.MainActivity}} show : false
>   06-23 09:53:52.149 17188-17188/hobby_pc.medispeak I/chromium:
>
> [INFO:CONSOLE(47)] "RV: Voice synthesis not supported", source:
>   https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js (47) 06-23
>   09:53:52.149 17188-17188/hobby_pc.medispeak I/chromium:
>
> [INFO:CONSOLE(49)] "RV: Enabling fallback mode", source:
>   https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js (49)

```
 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(99)] "speak.js: worker processing took 12513.00  ms", source: http://www.medispeak.eu/speakClient.js (99)
 06-23 09:52:15.789 12277-12277/hobby_pc.medispeak I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Failed to execute 'play' on 'HTMLMediaElement': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.", source: http://www.medispeak.eu/ (0)
 06-23 09:52:15.799 12277-12277/hobby_pc.medispeak I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(86)] "speak.js: wav processing took 2838.00 ms", source: http://www.medispeak.eu/speakClient.js (86)
 06-23 09:52:17.709 12277-12277/hobby_pc.medispeak I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(59)] "Uncaught (in promise) NotAllowedError: play() can only be initiated by a user gesture.", source: http://www.medispeak.eu/speakClient.js (59)
```

Comment: Mate, I can't really understand your question... Can you please try to rephrase it?

Comment: I updated the question, maybe this is better.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a an advanced webview library,
for example, [AdvancedWebView](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView).